# SkyDrive alternative with API access?

Tags: rest, api, onedrive

Is there any 3th party service (no MS) similar to skydrive (CRUD files in the cloud) free to use and with an official API (REST could be perfect but even SOAP can be ok)?

I don't need 100Gb, just few megs are ok, but accessible via API (I'm planning to develop a smartphone application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Comment: please add some more information. Answers with only links are not that useful and sometimes attract downvotes and even spam flags.